# Why Location is an Entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am reading the code of Cargo DDD sample. Can someone explain to me why the Location is Entity? I think it should be a Value Object. What do you think?

[Location class](http://code.google.com/p/ndddsample/source/browse/trunk/src/NDDDSample/app/domain/NDDDSample.Domain/Model/Locations/Location.cs)

Comment: I agree it might be more helpful to model a UnLocode as a value rather than an object with a proscribed lifetime, but you could really make a case either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location is an Entity cause it has an Identity to identify and its an integral part of the Domain. Cause cargo gets shipped from one source location over other locations to a specific destination location.

You need to identity the diffrent locations correctly by its identity and therefore you need a repository to get locations from data source or to insert new locations.

Answer (score 0):

I think, all about the implementation of entity is "which is it", but of value object is "what is it". The value object is always immutable and shared.

In the sample of Cargo, I think we should differ out the locations, not only what's about the location.